# Python Command Pattern using execute and instance variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a commander class, but can't get it to work properly:

```
#torbotCommander.py
from mongoconn import MongoConnection
class TorbotCommander(object):
    excecute = {
        'request': TorrentRequest,
        'list': ListTorrents,
        'fulfill': FulfillRequest
    }    
    def __init__(self, TorbotCommandObj):
        send(TorbotCommander.execute[TorbotCommandObj.__command](TorbotCommandObj))

    def TorrentRequest(self, TorbotCommandObj):
        print "request"
    def ListTorrents(self, TorbotCommandObj):
        print "list"
    def FulfillRequest(self, TorbotCommandObj):
        print "fulfill"
```

When I run this file, I get `name 'TorrentRequest' is not defined`, though. What don't I understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely because you're calling the TorrentRequest function here:

```
execute = {
    'request': TorrentRequest,
}
```

which is located before you actually define the TorrentRequest function in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your referencing the name `TorrentRequest` before you've created it. Python allows methods to be referenced before their definition, but the reference must be inside of your classes `__init__` method. This behavior can be seen using a simple example:

```
# Python 2
>>> class foo(object):
...     baz = bar
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
>>>
```

One might also think using `self` would work. It would not:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     baz = self.bar()
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...     def bar(self): 
...         pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
>>>
```

The easiest solution is to simply make `execute` an attribute of your class.